# Why this single and double quote make so much difference in output

Tags: regex, perl, shell

Why outputs of these two commands differ?

```
cat config.xml|perl -ne 'print $1,"\n" if /([0-9\.]+):161/'

cat config.xml|perl -ne "print $1,"\n" if /([0-9\.]+):161/"
```

First works as expected printing out matched group while seconds prints whole line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two main things wrong with your command.

First off, double quotes allow shell interpolation, and `$1` will be taken for a shell variable and replaced. Since it unlikely exists, it will be replaced with an empty string. So instead of `print $1`, you get `print`, which is shorthand for `print $_`, and is probably why the entire line prints.

Second, you have unescaped double quotes inside your command, so you are in fact passing three strings to Perl:

```
print ,
\n
 if /(....)/
```

As for why or how this works with your shell, I don't know, since I do not have access to your OS, nor know which one it is. In Windows, I get a Perl bareword warning for `n` (`Unquoted string "n" may clash with future reserved word at -e line 1.`) which means that the `\n` is interpreted as a string. Now, here's the tricky part. What we get is this:

```
print , \n if /.../
```

Which means that `\n` is no longer an argument to `print`, it is a statement that comes after `print` and it is in void context, so it gets ignored. We can see this by this warning (which I had to fake in my shell):

```
Useless use of single ref constructor in void context at -e line 1.
```

(Note that you do not get these warnings as you do not use warnings -- the `-w` switch)

So what we are left with is

```
print if /.../
```

Which is exactly the code for the behaviour you described: It prints the whole line when a match is found.

What you can do to visualize the problem in your shell is add the `-MO=Deparse` switch to your one-liner, as shown here:

```
C:\perl>perl -MO=Deparse -ne"print ,"\n" if /a/"
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    print($_), \'n' if /a/;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Now we can clearly see that the print statement is separated from the newline, and that the newline is a reference to a string.

---

**Solution:**

However, your code has other problems, and if done right you can avoid all the shell difficulties. First, you have a [UUOC (Useless Use of Cat)](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). A file argument can be given to perl when using the `-n` switch on the command line. Secondly, you do not need to use variables for this, you can simply print the return value of your regex:

```
perl -nlwe 'print for /(...)/' config.xml
```

The `-l` switch will handle newlines for you, and in this case add newline to the print. The `for` is necessary to avoid printing empty matches.

Answer (score 3):

Inside double quote, some stuffs are substituted ($variable, `command`, ..). While inside single quote, they are remained as is.

```
$ echo "$HOME"
/home/falsetru
$ echo '$HOME'
$HOME

$ echo "`echo 1`"
1
$ echo '`echo 1`'
`echo 1`
```

Nested quotes:

```
$ echo ""hello""
hello
$ echo '"hello"'
"hello"
$ echo "\"hello\""
"hello"
```

Escape double quotes, `$` to get same result:

```
cat config.xml | perl -ne "print \$1,\"\n\" if /([0-9\.]+):161/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Nested quotes.
2. Variables expand differently.

The first command has one string that happens to contain some double quotes. The variable is *not* expanded.

The second command has two strings with an unquoted `\n` in between. The variable *is* expanded.

Let's say `$1` contains "blah"

The first passes this string to perl:

```
print $1,"\n" if /([0-9\.]+):161/
```

the second, this:

```
print blah,\n if /([0-9\.]+):161/
```